# How to open a link in my application on Android

Tags: android, deep-linking

When I click on my website post from social media websites, I want to open this post (content) inside my application and not open in web browser.

For example : When click on `www.example.com/news/365` open this post into my application.

**I added this codes into manifest :**

```
<activity android:name=".singleVideo.view.SingleVideoActivity">

    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/news"
            android:scheme="http" />

    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

**And i add this codes in activity :**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

Now when I click on this link : `www.example.com/news/365`, it opens into my application, but it does not show the post contents (title, image, description and more ...).

How can I do it? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The thing you want to do is called deep linking. You've done what is said in https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html. Then you have to extract the needed info from the Uri data. And use your app, API and so on to display something. You can data.getLastPathSegment(). To get the 365 from "www.example.com/news/365" and use your API to get news 365 and display it inside of your app.

Comment: @toshkinl, yes my mean is deep link. can you send me simple code? please. i really need this

Comment: I don't think you really need a code example. You have to extract the data from the Uri data that the Intent gives you. If you show me your original Uri I can write a code to extract the data that you need.

Comment: @toshkinl, can you send me your email ? please

Comment: @toshkinl, are you here my bro?

Comment: hey @toshkinl, why not answer to me? :(

Comment: Hey, I can't give you my email. You can still ask questions and step by step create a complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use data.getPath() method.

that will returns 365 
(maybe.. read document. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)

and use your API (REST API )!

if you have not API. just make or use HTML Parsing Library. 
(like jsoup https://jsoup.org)

Comment: Thanks, when write data.getPath(), where set this? i have a API and fecth items from this

Comment: when use this : `data.getPath()` . show me this error : ` java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.mototel.mototel/com.sepandar.xengine.singleVideo.view.SingleVideoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object reference`

Comment: after get data in your activity. 
not exactly getPath() method. I'm not read document all.
I used query parameter (like this : http://www.example.com/news?id=365 ) .
in my case , i use data.getQueryParameter("id") method .!

Comment: the important thing is The data (get from Intent) dose not have Your Contents (title, images, etc.. ).
You can get contents from your server or web page document (HTML).

Comment: Can you send me your email? please my bro.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as Deep Linking.

On the web, the URL `www.example.com/news/365` is just an address that your web browser uses to request a specific HTML document. This HTML document contains code to define what content will be displayed when it is loaded. The address `www.example.com/news/365` itself doesn't contain any content.

What you have done by adding these snippets to your app's Manifest and Activity is associate the address `www.example.com/news/365` with a specific activity inside your app, in addition to a specific HTML page on the web. This means that if your app is installed and that address is opened, the user will be given a choice (or not, if the `autoVerify` configuration is implemented properly) between opening the address in a web browser or in your app. However, it's important to know that `www.example.com/news/365` *still doesn't contain any content itself*. As far as your app is concerned, this is just an empty location. You still need to do the work of retrieving the address and using it to determine what image/title/description to display to the user.

Without knowing the full details of how your app and your API are set up, it's not really possible to give you example code. The official [Android deep linking guide](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) is a good place to start.

Alternatively, you can look into a deep linking platform like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team), which makes all of this much simpler since all you need to do is pass a set of `key:value` pairs with each link. We also let your links work even when the app isn't installed yet, which is known as **deferred deep linking**.